# C++ another class member and overloading operator

Tags: c++, class, member

I need to write program as follow:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
    public:
        double X;
        double Y;

        Point(){}

        Point(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
};

class Circle
{
    public:
        Point P;
        double R;

        Circle(){}

        Circle(Point p, double r)
        {
            P = p;
            R = r;
        }

        Circle operator +(Circle C1, Circle C2)
        {
            return Circle(C1.Point, C1.R + C2.R);
        }

        Circle operator -(Circle C1, Circle C2)
        {
            return Circle(C2.Point, C1.R - C2.R);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Circle c1, c2, cr1, cr2, ck1, ck2;

    // create c1
    // create c2

    cr1 = c1 + c2;
    // display cr1
    cr2 = c2 + c1;
    // display cr2

    ck1 = c1 - c2;
    // display ck1
    ck2 = c2 - c1;
    // display ck2

    return 0;
}
```

Two classes Point and Circle, where Circle have member of Point as it's center, two operators to add and to subtract two Circles.

And I can't compile this, what is wrong?

```
#################################################################################
```

EDIT:
After correction it looks like that, and works perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
    public:
        double X, Y;

        Point(){}

        Point(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
};

class Circle
{
    public:
        double R;
        Point P;

        Circle(){}

        Circle(Point p, double b)
        {
            P = p;
            R = b;
        }

        Circle operator+(const Circle& C1)
        {
            Circle C;
            C.P = this->P;
            C.R = this->R + C1.R;
            return C;
        }

        Circle operator -(const Circle& C1)
        {
            Circle C;
            C.P = C1.P;
            C.R = this->R - C1.R;
            return C;
        }
};

int main()
{
    double X, Y, R;
    cout << "Coordinates for C1:" << endl;
    cout << "\tX: ";
    cin >> X;
    cout << "\tY: ";
    cin >> Y;
    cout << "Radius for C1:";
    cin >> R;
    Circle *c1 = new Circle(Point(X, Y), R);

    cout << "Coordinates for C2:" << endl;
    cout << "\tX: ";
    cin >> X;
    cout << "\tY: ";
    cin >> Y;
    cout << "Radius for C2:";
    cin >> R;
    Circle *c2 = new Circle(Point(X, Y), R);

    Circle cs1 = c1->operator+(*c2);
    Circle cs2 = c1->operator-(*c2);

    Circle cr1 = c2->operator+(*c1);
    Circle cr2 = c2->operator-(*c1);

    cout << "cs1([" << cs1.P.X << ", " << cs1.P.Y << "], " << cs1.R << ")" << endl;
    cout << "cs2([" << cs2.P.X << ", " << cs2.P.Y << "], " << cs2.R << ")" << endl;
    cout << "cr1([" << cr1.P.X << ", " << cr1.P.Y << "], " << cr1.R << ")" << endl;
    cout << "cr2([" << cr2.P.X << ", " << cr2.P.Y << "], " << cr2.R << ")" << endl;

    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Errors are extremely important in helping to figure out what a problem is. Experienced programmers can often figure out a mistake from the error alone.

Comment: You have (at least) one mistake: It's not `C1.Point` it's `C1.P` in `operator+` (same for C2 in `operator-`)

Comment: You know, your overload of op+ / op- violates the rule of least astonishment. Please read: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421708)

Comment: I would expect... I don't know, maybe a union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect overloaded operators. Look at the following code:

```
Circle operator +(const Circle& C)
{
    return Circle(this->P, this->R + C.R);
}

Circle operator -(const Circle& C)
{
    return Circle(this->P, this->R - C.R);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define operators like `operator-` inside your class as member functions, then when you use it

```
C3 = C1 + C2;
```

The compiler is actually calling your member function like

```
C3 = C1.operator+(C2);
```

From this you should be able to figure out that operators as member functions only takes *one* argument, and that the first object in the operator is the `this` object.

For stand-alone (non-member) functions they need two arguments.

---

You might want to check e.g. [this reference on operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).